# How to check if unit and function exists?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm using Delphi 11. Is there a way to run a specific function inside a TDataModule, but only if this datamodule exists on my project ?

I need a way to check if the datamodule exists and call the function as string, because some projects will have this datamodule added, others not.

Instead of this :

```
myDataModule.myfunction(param);
```

Would be something like this imaginary code :

```
if TDataModule(findcomponent('myDataModule')) <> nil then
   TDataModule(findcomponent('myDataModule')).call('myfunction','param');
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to do your .Call('myfunction ...?  You could use the `as` operator ...

Comment: @MartynA I don't know how to do this, the code is just an imaginary example

Comment: How are you including the data module?

Comment: Well, read up on it: see the section 'The as Operator' in https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Class_References.

Comment: @Martyn if you could use `as` here to cast to the data module type and bind statically to the method, then you'd have used the unit and the entire question would dissolve.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Indeed.  "Dissolve": what a great way to put it.

Comment: Have a look a [`$IF Declared()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/IF_directive_(Delphi))

Comment: Your code architecture feels wrong somehow. At least you should encapsulate this in e.g. a base class with an empty virtual method. And when your projects needs the Datamodule function, use a class with that method overridden and inject it to the calling code.

Comment: Or in other words, this is an OOP principle (don't remember right now, if one of the SOLIDs): encapsulate, what can change!

Answer (score 4):

A lightweight solution could be *Messages* (those from *System.Messaging*).

1. Declare a new *TMessage* descendant holding the parameters needed for the call
2. When the datamodule is created it *Subscribes* to this message type with a handler doing the actions.
3. Instead of searching for the datamodule just *Send* the message.

Comment: Maybe simpler: Declare a suitable event type (`procedure ... of object` or `reference ...`) and event variable in a common unit and initialize it to `nil`. In the data module unit, change the event variable to a suitable handler.

Comment: @UliGerhardt Yes, that is possible, too. It just restricts to one subscriber instead of multiple ones. Recently I tend to the more flexible approach.

Answer (score -1):

This may or may not be applicable to your situation...  But that seems like the kind of situation I would solve with a multicast event.

Your code would call `Event.Execute('Param')` instead of `myDataModule.myfunction(param)`.

The part of your code responsible for "importing" and creating the datamodule would register to the event. Something like :

```
EventClient := TEventClient.create(
                    procedure (const AParam : ParamType)
                    begin
                      myDataModule.myfunction(AParam)
                    end);
EventClient.Observe(Event);
```

Now, this approach makes sense if the reasons to call your function is "event-like", but this might make less sense in other contexts.

As for library implementing multicast event, I can't recommend any as I always used a proprietary one. If you need inspiration to implement your own, you can look at TMultiCaster in unit Vcl.AppEvnts which implements more or less the same concept.